# How can I get the url of a Django ImageField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, image-gallery

I am using a modelformset_factory method with forms containing only an ImageField. The Model the forms are based on contains a user field that has a many-to-one relationship with a User Model that extends AbstractUser([See Extending User Model with Abstract User](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)). Currently, each instance of a user has a correlating User Profile, but I would also like to allow the user to upload a gallery of images to their profile.

**models.py**

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) 
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_gallery', blank=True, null=True)

    def create_gallery(sender, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            user_gallery = Gallery.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
            user_gallery.save();
post_save.connect(create_gallery, sender=User)
```

**forms.py**

```
class GalleryForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.ImageField(label='FormImage')
class Meta:
    model = Gallery
    fields = ['image']
```

**views.py**

```
def EditProfile(request):
    GalleryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Gallery, form=GalleryForm, extra=3, max_num=3)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = GalleryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                my_image = form['image']
                photo = Gallery(user=request.user, image=my_image)
                photo.save()

            return render(request, 'user_handler/editprofile.html', {'formset': formset})
    else:
        formset = GalleryFormSet()
    return render(request, 'user_handler/editprofile.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**Template**

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ formset.management_form }}

        {% for form in formset %}
            {{form.image}}
            <img src="{{form.image.url}}"/>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The problem I'm have is that using {{ form.image }} produces this result: [image]

... and using {{ form.image.url }} within an image's source tag produces absolute nothing at all. When I inspect the element I contain it in, it states the source is unknown. Obviously, the images are being saved in the DB as I'd like, but I can't get the .url functionality to work. And YES, I do have the media root an all defined:

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'   
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'HighlightPage_Project/media')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.Login_Redirect),
url(r'^account/', include('user_handler_app.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to replace your code with the following code:

**views.py**

```
def EditProfile(request):
    GalleryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Gallery, form=GalleryForm, extra=3, max_num=3)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = GalleryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                my_image = form['image']
                photo = Gallery(user=request.user, image=my_image)
                photo.save()

            return render(request, 'user_handler/editprofile.html', {'formset': formset})
    else:
        user_images = Gallery.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        initial_images = [{'image': i.image, 'image_url': i.image.url} for i in user_images if i.image]
        formset = GalleryFormSet(initial=initial_images)
    return render(request, 'user_handler/editprofile.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**Template**

```
<form id="post_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}

    {% for form in formset %}
        {{form.image}}
        <img src="{{form.initial.image_url}}"/>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: I didn't see this until now, but I've added the image_url log into my new version of this code (seen in my most recent question), and I am getting the URL of the uploaded image. It's as if Django's ImageField.url() function isn't working, but yours is. @OmarHafez

Comment: If it worked for you then mark it as right answer buddy, I'll be thankful  @AustinCopeland

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace your code with the following code:

```
<img src="{{form.image.url}}"/>
```

with:

```
<img src="{{form.instance.image.url}}"/>
```